# Arrangement of text fields

Tags: html, input

I want to arrange the field like this:

```
 ____________________________
|input username     |        |
|___________________| input  | 
|input  password    | login  |
|___________________|________|
```

My HTML and CSS looks like:

```css
.login {   width: 300px; /*width: 100%;*/}
input[type="submit"] {width: 50%; height: 50px;}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {  width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="login">
     <input type="text" id="username" > 
     <input type="password" id="password">
     <input type="submit" id="login" >
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should look to provide some background information regarding solutions you have tried. It is more likely that someone will help if you have shown a reasonable amount of effort rather than simply asking someone to do the work for you.

Comment: You can use bootstrap to do that, or allot of CSS with floats..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to make minor change in your code,

there are many approaches to get that output, use table, position absolute way, or display:inline-block - as you wish!

https://jsfiddle.net/happy2deepak/8moLauu7/

### CSS

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;} /* box sizing reset */

.login {   width: 300px; /*width: 100%;*/}
input[type="submit"] {width: 100%; height: 50px;}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {  width: 100%;height: 25px;padding: 0;} /* gave height to match button height */

.login {display: block;list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
.login>li {display: table-cell;width: 50%;vertical-align: top;}
```

### HTML

```
<ul class="login">
        <li class="fields">
            <input type="text" id="username" >
            <input type="password" id="password">
        </li>
        <li class="sub-btn"><input type="submit" id="login" ></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap but if you want simple css then you can place your input fields in a class and then float it left

```
<div class="login">
<div class="logininputs">
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="password" id="password">
</div>
<input type="submit" id="login">
```

And  CSS:

```
.login {
   width: 100%;
}
input[type="submit"] {
   width: 50%;
   height: 50px;
}
.logininputs {
   width: 50%;
   float:left;
   padding:0 10px;
}
input {
   width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td rowspan=2><input type="submit" value="Login"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```